# How to read from byte object in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am able to tar a file successfully on the fly using `subprocess.run`, but I was not able to send the tar file using send_file option due to the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Using `subprocess.Popen` I was able to tar and send files successfully which are small in size (barely upto 1GB).But there is a problem while taring the files up to 4GB with `subprocess.Popen`, as subprocess.Popen is using memory to tar.

So I have moved to subprocess.run...but this is failing with the above error.

Please find the code snippet:

```
process = subprocess.run(['tar', '-cvf', '-', test_dir], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
send_file(process.stdout, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=test_dir.tar)
```

`send_file` is from flask framework.

Would appreciate any help with the above.

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read`

This mean ability to `.read` is expected, as you already have `bytes` it should be enough to use `io.BytesIO` from io built-in module like so

```
import io
```

...

```
process = subprocess.run(['tar', '-cvf', '-', test_dir], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = process.stdout
send_file(io.BytesIO(data), as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=test_dir.tar)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, I have used Bytes.IO but its returning 0  bytes i.e. empty tar file

Please find the updated code snippet:

    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    buffer.write(process.stdout)
    response = send_file(buffer, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=f'{base_dir}.tar')

Please suggest how to proceed further.

Comment: @GiriVarshini if you use `io.BytesIO` this way you need to seek to start after writing; add `buffer.seek(0)` immediately before `send_file(`...

Comment: I've used buffer.seek(0) but it is working for small tar files only for large files above 4Gb this process is not working. Please suggest any other solution to send large files using send_file option. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @GiriVarshini you might try: let `tar` create file, then `open` it in python and provide created filehandle to `send_file`. This file should be then deleted, but I do not know how to make it sure it would not be deleted too early